# Script to install Ubuntu and same set of programs on several computers

Tags: scripts, software-installation

I have several computers at different locations, and I want all of them to be set up in exactly the same way.
Is it possible to write a script which I can run once I have installed a new Ubuntu OS to automatically download and install all the programs which I need?
I would like to install programs such as

- Google Chrome
- R
- Eclipse
- etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is as following

```
#! /bin/bash
mkdir  install9327
cd install9327
wget -c <link to google chrome.deb>
wget -c <link to etc.deb>
sudo dpkg -i *
sudo apt-get -y install r-base-core eclipse
cd ..
rm -r ./install9327
spd-say "mission completed, no guarantee of success."
```

Make the script executable with

```
sudo chmod +x /path_to_script/filename.sh    # filename.sh is your script name.
```

This script will create a folder, download chrome and etc, install them, install R and eclipse and then clear all the stuff.At last it gives a spoken message.

In case of failure(due to disconnection,broken dependencies etc), this script will just leave a folder behind, which you may want to delete.

> **NOTE:-** You have to manually ensure the links to google chrome and etc, do not install wrong packages on wrong distro.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Diskless Remote Boot Linux and Clonezilla. The idea here being that you would install the Desired OS on a dedicated server with all the apps, clone it and then use DRBL to install the image via Clonezilla.

DRBL: http://drbl.org/
Article describing all this: www.linuxjournal.com/article/10884